# Django - Queryset alternative for model method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to retrieve a set of values obtained by a model method and filtered according to the properties of another model.

I have two models:

```
class Variety(models.Model):
    product_group = models.ForeignKey(ProductGroup)
    variety_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)

class ProductPart(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    part = models.ForeignKey(Variety)
    qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=28, decimal_places=2)

    def _total_qty_sold(self):
        sold = SalesRecord.objects.values().filter(sale_item=self.product)
        total_sold = [SalesRecord['sales_qty'] for SalesRecord in sold]
        return sum(total_sold) * self.qty
    total_qty_sold = property(_total_qty_sold)
```

In Variety, I need to sum all of the `total_qty_sold` where `part` matches the `variety_name`, so that I know how much of the variety has been sold among all `ProductPart` entries.

I thought about using a model manager, but [from reading the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/), it seems like all filters have to be hard coded into the manager. Since the names and amounts of Varieties will change, this wouldn't really work for me. I need to retrieve these values based on the Model's `self`. Sort of like:

```
def _total_sales_of_materials(self):
        sold = ProductPart.objects.filter(part=self).values()
        total_materials_sold = sum([ProductPart['total_qty_sold'] for ProductPart in sold])
        return total_materials_sold
    total_sales_of_materials = property(_total_sales_of_materials)
```

But I can't actually obtain `total_qty_sold` this way. Somehow I need to get ahold of all values of `total_sales_of_materials` for all objects where `ProductPart.part` matches `Variety.variety_name`. Is there a Django trick that I am missing, or do I need to change my approach via Python?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went back to the basics with a simple for loop:

```
def _total_sales_of_part_materials(self):
        sold = ProductPart.objects.filter(part=self)
        total_part_materials_sold = 0
        for object in sold:
            total_part_materials_sold += object.total_qty_sold
        return total_part_materials_sold
    total_sales_of_part_materials = property(_total_sales_of_part_materials)
```

Works like a charm. For some reason I thought this wouldn't work if list comprehension didn't. Now I understand that list comprehension incorporates Django's "QuerySet" mechanism that can only interact with database objects.

Fortunately you can still fish out that model method out with a good old-fashioned for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Django queryset is rich in customization. You can customize in many ways. You should read the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate) to satisfy your need. For example the method -

```
def _total_sales_of_materials(self):
    sold = ProductPart.objects.filter(part=self).values()
    total_materials_sold = sum([ProductPart['total_qty_sold'] for ProductPart in sold])
    return total_materials_sold
```

can be packed into one query -

```
def _total_sales_of_materials(self):
    total_sold = ProductPart.objects.filter(part=self).aggregate(Sum('qty'))
    return total_sold
```

and this is mentioned here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate

You can also build dynamic queries using `Q` object.

The same query can be written as -

```
total_sold = ProductPart.objects.filter(Q(**{'part':self})).aggregate(Sum('qty'))
```

Comment: Hmm aggregate doesn't seem to want to sum: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. Maybe because it is returning a dictionary value?

Comment: which database backend are you using? is it MongoDB?

Comment: BTW, `ProductPart` does not have a property named `'total_qty_sold'` in database it is  `'qty'`.  Try again, I changed my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem I am bringing to the forum. `total_qty_sold` is not a database table, but a model method. I am looking for a way to access the information from that model method, given a particular variety. Basically I need the sum of the results for the `total_qty_sold` method of all `ProductPart` objects, whose `part` = `Variety.variety_name`. I need to retrieve `total_qty_sold` results similar to how your solution is retrieving `qty`.